# Playframework: How can I disable session / cookies on specific action?

Tags: java, playframework

For a specific controller action I want to turn off cookies. I've tried to remove the cookie Map, but that doesn't seem to work. I need to completely remove all response headers except my own.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to wrap the response with a wrapper with `response.current.set(new CookieLessResponseWrapper(response.current()))`. Works ok for me.

Here is the code for the Response wrapper if anyone is interested.

```
package helpers;

import play.mvc.Http.Response;

public class CookieLessResponseWrapper extends Response {
    private Response wrappedResponse;

    public CookieLessResponseWrapper(Response response) {
        this.wrappedResponse = response;
    }

    @Override
    public void accessControl(String allowOrigin, boolean allowCredentials) {
        wrappedResponse.accessControl(allowOrigin, allowCredentials);
    }

    @Override
    public void accessControl(String allowOrigin, String allowMethods,
            boolean allowCredentials) {
        wrappedResponse.accessControl(allowOrigin, allowMethods, allowCredentials);
    }

    @Override
    public void accessControl(String allowOrigin) {
        wrappedResponse.accessControl(allowOrigin);
    }

    @Override
    public void cacheFor(String etag, String duration, long lastModified) {
        wrappedResponse.cacheFor(etag, duration, lastModified);
    }

    @Override
    public void cacheFor(String duration) {
        wrappedResponse.cacheFor(duration);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        return wrappedResponse.getHeader(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(Object o) {
        wrappedResponse.print(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCookie(String name) {
        wrappedResponse.removeCookie(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        wrappedResponse.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentTypeIfNotSet(String contentType) {
        wrappedResponse.setContentTypeIfNotSet(contentType);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCookie(String name, String value, String domain,
            String path, Integer maxAge, boolean secure, boolean httpOnly) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setCookie(String name, String value, String domain,
            String path, Integer maxAge, boolean secure) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setCookie(String name, String value, String duration) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setCookie(String name, String value) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
        wrappedResponse.setHeader(name, value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/SfpnAX5Crm4/Hb8yo9GiEr8J) solution when Googling this problem. It does the same thinng you try, removing cookies map, but it is done in an method which is annotated with `@Finally`.

I believe cookies map is filled after `render()` but before any `@Finally` annotated class.

Credits to Alex Jarvis on Google Groups, code is copied for reference:

```
/** 
 * Removes cookies from all responses. 
 * 
 * This is because cookies are not required in stateless webservice and 
 * we don't want to send any unnecessary information to the client. 
 * 
 * @author Alex Jarvis 
 */ 
public class NoCookieFilter extends Controller { 

        /** An empty cookie map to replace any cookies in the response. */ 
        private static final Map<String, Http.Cookie> cookies = new HashMap<String, Http.Cookie>(0); 

        /** 
         * When the configuration property 'cookies.enabled' equals false, 
         * this Finally filter will replace the cookies in the response with an empty Map. 
         */ 

        @Finally 
        protected static void removeCookies() { 
            boolean cookiesEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(Play.configuration.getProperty("cookies.enabled")); 
            if (!cookiesEnabled) { 
                    response.cookies = cookies; 
            } 
        } 

}
```

Usage: For any controller you want to be "cookieless" annotate it with

> @With(NoCookieFilter.class)

(Tested in Play 1.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to clear all headers, in your action, with:

```
Http.Response.current().reset();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Looks like reset() is just for clearing the body (out.clear()).

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that the Session is a Cookie. I don't believe that you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

How about use discarding the whole session for each request as a workaround?

Discarding the whole session

```
Ok("Bye").withNewSession
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaSessionFlash#Discarding-the-whole-session