# How do I disable Sessions in Play Framework completely?

Tags: playframework

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429551/playframework-how-can-i-disable-session-cookies-on-specific-action) where the OP wanted to disable session handling for *a certain* controller action. Since I am working on a completely stateless app, I want to completely disable all session handling in the complete app though. Filtering every request to overwrite an attribute of the response for this feels kind of overkill. Especially since all the preparations like generating a session ID, [signing the session data](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash#How-it-is-different-in-Play), and whatever else Play is doing, are still carried out.

Is there any other—less expensive—way of preventing the Play framework from creating a session in the first place?